# Odd behavior using the MAX3323EEPE to translate RS232 output to TTL logic levels

Tags: rs232, max232

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc8iH9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using the [MAX3323EEPE](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/MAX3322E_MAX3323E-3128258.pdf) Maxim IC in order to *attempt* to take RS-232 output from a peripheral and shift it down to TTL logic levels so a small AVR processor can communicate serially with said peripheral.

This IC in particular is a 16-pin DIP as it only has one channel for RX/TX. I am using 5 V logic on the MCU side and have chosen the capacitors according to the datasheet.

I also attached a picture of the rat's nest breadboard I am testing it on.

[image]

I know the colors are horrible but this is what I had on me. To clarify, you can see the four required capacitors on the left, sized for 5 V. The bottom two pins on the left side are RX/TX. I bridged the power and ground rails. One of the wires to ground on the right side (white cable, 3rd from the bottom) goes to my MCU ground, and the green cable on the power rail, 4th from the bottom goes to MCU 5 V. First red cable on the left ground rail goes to the ground pin on the RS-232 output.

The only other addition is that I added a 0.1 μF ceramic capacitor from the VCC pin #18 (top right of MAX) to ground just for decoupling as is specified in the datasheet. After that bypass the VCC is connected to the power rail (which is at 5 V via the MCU).

I poked an LED into the TX of the RS-232 side and am getting 0.2 second "heartbeats" as is expected from the peripheral, but when putting the LED on RX/TX on the TTL side it shows both as high, the bottom right pin #9 as particularly high (LED is much brighter on that trace).

I feel as though I am missing something extremely stupid but given all the permutations of switching RX and TX and switching which side is TTL vs. RS-232 I am sure I have toasted the IC at this point.

In the interest of not burning another IC if I already have, what are your thoughts on why I am seeing such odd behavior?

Comment: You are likely following a schematic of some sort.  You'll get more input if you include the schematic in your question.  Edit the question and use the built in schematic editor to reproduce what you have built or attach an image of the schematic (citing the source).  More details about your source peripheral would also be helpful.

Comment: I do not have an example I am working off of, just the linked datasheet. That sheet does however have an example loopback circuit in it. I will rig up a schematic and update asap.

Comment: When you poked the LED there, did you use a series resistor for the LED? Can you clarify what you think is odd behaviour, what is the exact setup and what do you expect or don't expect?

Comment: I notice that the RX or TX have enable pins. You didn't mention them.

Comment: @Wendall TXenable and RXenable are both driven high along with VL and SHDN.

Comment: @BitBrigade The supply is incorrect and TTL and RS232 sides are swapped. Can you fix those and tell where you put the LED and were wondering why it lit up brightly? 5V caps are also not enough for the chip, the charge pump outputs are 5.5V.

Comment: @Justme Not with a series resistor, I wasn't worried about blowing out the LED. I will clarify on the odd behavior. 1) I have had intermittent success with the circuit a handful of times, just doesn't work a majority of the time. 2) The TTL outputs seem to be driven high by default but at different levels, despite the RS-232 inputs being either low or high/low with a change every .2 seconds. I have switched the TX and RX both sides for sanity's sake.

Comment: @Justme Are you saying to make those changes in the circuit or schematic? Caps are 50V ceramic. LED was put in between the RS232 TX and the corresponding RS232 Tin, then between the TTL Tout and MCU RX pin to see if it was getting the same heartbeats across the chip.

Comment: @BitBrigade You can't put a LED in series with a data output and data input pins. Or you can but it won't work. 50V caps are fine. I thought they were 5V, but you meant you selected the capacitances based on 5V supply being used.

Comment: @The LED was placed between the pin "under test" and ground rail just to see if I was getting the signal the peripheral theoretically should be giving me. I've seen them done that way on a RS-232 breakout board as "TX/RX" indicators before so it was just a sanity check. The LEDs were luckily already damaged and fair enough about the IC max current, I am not sure what it is for those pins but the LED in question pulled no more than 100mA from a benchtop DC supply so I figured the MCU was at least fine, (rated for 500mA in short bursts, 100 constant).

Comment: @BitBrigade Small AVR processors have IO pin absolute maximum ratings in the ballpark of 50mA, not 500mA, so off by 10x.

Comment: You’re wasting your and our time by not including a complete schematic of what you tested, LEDs and everything. From what I can sniff it’s not a sure thing that you connected those LEDs correctly. Furthermore, this circuit will work just fine per datasheet, so the problem is what you are NOT showing us. Also, serial transmissions are short. You will see nothing by just looking at a LED without at least an inverter so that the LED is off in the line idle state. You need an oscilloscope to look at the signals, and you need to show it tracings in the question. Otherwise it is unanswerable.

Comment: Pins 8 and 10 are your 232 inputs, while 11 and 13 are your TTL outputs.  You have them criss-crossed.  Look at page 11 of your datasheet.

Comment: @evildemonic Those particular pins you are referencing are on the 3322E which has one more channel than mine and thus a different pin configuration

Comment: I see, 7 and 8 are your 232 then, while 9 and 10 are you TTL.  It sounds like you are aware of this even though your schematic shows the opposite?

Comment: @evildemonic You are correct, sorry for the confusion. I was belly deep in the "peripheral" in question yelling out info to my buddy so he could let me know what people's ideas were.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica You are correct about needing the inverter! I forgot that the UART idles high. I would give the full schematic if I knew what exactly I was connecting it to, unfortunately it is somewhat of a blackbox. I promise you if I had ready access to an oscilloscope that's the first thing I would have done, but I cannot get one right at this moment, I have a handheld multimeter so unfortunately the LED was better than the alternative. I didn't mean for the question to insinuate that an answer was expected STAT, again it was more of a sanity check.

Comment: @BitBrigade You don't need an inverter. All you need to do is to wire the LED so that a logic low level turns the LED on, meaning the LED anode side goes to 5V and cathode side goes to data wire (through a resistor, obviously).

Comment: @Justme, I did just that, thank you friend!

Answer (score 1):

It's an RS-232 transceiver.

The TTL side is supposed to idle at logic high.

UARTs idle high too. As the tranceivers invert, it makes a TTL logic high to match a RS-232 negative voltage.

It is unclear how you have connected it, but MCU TXD output must go to TTL side transmitter input TIN and thus TOUT is the RS-232 transmit output.

Likewise, RS-232 receive input is RIN, which is ROUT on the TTL output side which must connect to MCU RXD input.

And poking a LED to any of the data lines without a series resistor is a poor idea. Not only do you risk damaging the LED, but without a resistor, the LED clamps the voltage to its forward voltage, and it will likely draw too much current that likely exceeds MCU or transceiver absolute maximum safe current limits and thus might damage the ICs too. Use a resistor, or measure things with tools like multimeter, oscilloscope or logic analyzer.

Also if you did connect the RS-232 side to the MCU, it sure may stop working or get damaged permanently from the over- and undervoltage. It does have protection, so it might survive, but any excess current clamped by IO protection to supply might raise the supply voltage too high.

And the LED should not have been in series. For example: MCU logic inputs are high impedance CMOS inputs. Under normal circumstances, no current will flow into and out of a CMOS input pin. Putting a LED between a logic input and logic output both won't make the LED light up as there will be no current through it to light it up as there is no voltage difference, and even if there would be a slight current or voltage difference due to internal pull-up or pull-down resistors, the voltage drop over a LED would make the input not see proper logic level signals between the required logic level thresholds.